# pattern matching in asterisk apps dialplan

Tags: asterisk

I need to make pattern for asterisk sip calling like this way.

1. Pattern consist only "*","#" and 0-9 digits
2. pattern's first arguments is optional for "+" symbols.

like it matches

```
*1203#023212232
+*1203#122
12345555
```

but reject these cases

```
3434+23443
*2334%2323
```

I prepared pattern like this way

```
exten => _[*|#|+|0-9].,1,Answer()
```

but this is also accept following pattern too which I do not want to match.

```
*2334%2323
```

Comment: How many `#` and `*` are allowed? And in which position?

Comment: no limit also "+" allowed only at the beginning (atmost one time) and no other symbols.

Comment: @JKB Thanks for you answer but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

You can use the [REGEX function](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Function_REGEX)

**More details**

*Check the REGEX function documentation*

Type "core show function REGEX" on your asterisk cli:

```
asthost*CLI> core show function REGEX

  -= Info about function 'REGEX' =-

[Synopsis]
Check string against a regular expression.

[Description]
Return '1' on regular expression match or '0' otherwise
Please note that the space following the double quotes separating the regex
from the data is optional and if present, is skipped. If a space is desired at
the beginning of the data, then put two spaces there; the second will not be
skipped.

[Syntax]
REGEX("regular expression" string)

[Arguments]
Not available

[See Also]
Not available
```

*Write your dialplan*

extensions.conf file:

```
[default]
exten  => _[*#+0-9].,1,Set(match=${REGEX("^\\+?[0-9#*]+$" ${EXTEN})})
same   =>            n,GotoIf($["${match}" = "1"]?proceed:endcall)
same   =>            n(proceed),Answer()
same   =>            n(endcall),Hangup()
```

*Reload your dialplan*

Type "dialplan reload" on your asterisk cli:

```
asthost*CLI> dialplan reload
```

*Check your dialplan*

Type "dialplan show default" on your asterisk cli:

```
asthost*CLI> dialplan show default
[ Context 'default' created by 'pbx_config' ]
  '_[*#+0-9].' =>   1. Set(match=${REGEX("^\\+?[0-9#*]+$" ${EXTEN})}) [extensions.conf:7]
                    2. GotoIf($["${match}" = "1"]?proceed:endcall) [extensions.conf:8]
     [proceed]      3. Answer()                                   [extensions.conf:9]
     [endcall]      4. Hangup()                                   [extensions.conf:10]

-= 1 extension (4 priorities) in 1 context. =-
```

*Test your dialplan*

Start call from your SIP endpoint of just originate a call via [Local-Channel](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Local+Channel). Don't forget to set verbose level to 3, so you can see the dialplan output.

```
asthost*CLI> core set verbose 3
Console verbose was OFF and is now 3.
asthost*CLI> channel originate Local/*1203#023212232@default application Hangup
    -- Called *1203#023212232@default
    -- Executing [*1203#023212232@default:1] Set("Local/*1203#023212232@default-00000019;2", "match=1") in new stack
    -- Executing [*1203#023212232@default:2] GotoIf("Local/*1203#023212232@default-00000019;2", "1?proceed:endcall") in new stack
    -- Goto (default,*1203#023212232,3)
    -- Executing [*1203#023212232@default:3] Answer("Local/*1203#023212232@default-00000019;2", "") in new stack
    -- Local/*1203#023212232@default-00000019;1 answered
  == Spawn extension (default, *1203#023212232, 3) exited non-zero on 'Local/*1203#023212232@default-00000019;2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Asterisk support this much flexibility in regex expression.

The best way to achieve this is , pass this extension variable to an AGI and do the regex match there .

```
     exten => _.,1,AGI(Your AGI SCRIPT,${EXTEN})  // Pass the extension number to your Agi script.If that match your requirement set an agi variable **match** to 1 

     exten => s,n,GotoIf($["${match}" = "1"]?proceed:endcall) //Check the match variable status and proceed based on that 

     exten => s,n(proceed),Answer()
     exten => s,n(endcall),Hangup()
```

This is just an option of achieving your requirement

Comment: Yes, I am thinking in the same way too cause I do not able to find out another way. Also the above solution reject pattern when first digit occur with + sign.

Comment: exten => _.,1,AGI(Your AGI SCRIPT,${EXTEN})  // This will match all string previously it match's only numbers